# gradle configure plugin default during execution phase

Tags: plugins, gradle, execution

I am new to gradle. I am trying to use a plugin but I want to change the default values of a plugin during execution

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-ospackage-plugin:2.0.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'os-package-base'
```

Setting plugin defaults:

```
def version_local = version //project.version
ospackage {
    version = version_local
    .......
    .......
}
```

I am using another plugin(gradle-release) which changes the version of an artifact and the value of it is present in project.version. The tasks of this release plugin executes before the buildRpm task of this plugin(ospackage)

I want to use the value of the version present in project.version during execution. But looks like the value is being set prior to execution of any tasks. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code seems to do it.

```
buildRpm.doFirst {
    version = project.version
}
```

Explanation: doFirst is an action which only gets run during execution phase of gradle, right before running buildRpm.